# Peculiar performance variance with small arrays

Tags: arrays, performance, rust

As part of a larger project (of N-body simulations) I started working with arrays of f32s using const generics to represent algebraic vectors. Those vectors can then be of any size, but I'm especially interested in the ones of length 2 and 3.

I noticed that performance with arrays of length 2 was worse (a lot worse!) compared to similarly sized arrays (length 1 or 3 for example) in a certain scenario I need for my project.

This is the scenario, or rather a shortened version of it:

```
fn fold<const N: usize>(v: Vec<Array<N>>) -> Vec<Array<N>> {
    let result = v.iter().map(|a1| {
        v.iter().fold(Array::default(), |acc, a2| {
            let d = *a2 - *a1;

            acc + d
        })
    });

    result.collect()
}
```

The arrays are wrapped in a newtype called `Array` implementing operators for simplicity, but the results are the same without that wrapper.

Using criterion with Vecs lengthed from 10 to 500 of random arrays, I benched this function and generated the following graph for differently sized arrays:
[image: 1]

As you can see performance is a lot worse for arrays of length 2 compared to the rest. I'm unable to understand why this specific scenario leads to such performance variance, so I'm hoping someone can help me figure this out because this has slowed down my progress significantly.

### Edit

Interestingly, it seems like this is not the case using f64s, the results I shared were with f32s.

Here's the the full criterion setup as requested in a comment:

```
use criterion::{black_box, criterion_group, criterion_main, BenchmarkId, Criterion};
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct Array<const DIM: usize>(pub [f32; DIM]);

impl<const DIM: usize> Default for Array<DIM> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self([0.0; DIM])
    }
}

impl<const DIM: usize> std::ops::Add for Array<DIM> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        let mut result = Array::default();
        for (i, val) in result.0.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            *val = self.0[i] + rhs.0[i];
        }
        result
    }
}

impl<const DIM: usize> std::ops::Sub for Array<DIM> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn sub(self, rhs: Self) -> Self::Output {
        let mut result = Array::default();
        for (i, val) in result.0.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            *val = self.0[i] - rhs.0[i];
        }
        result
    }
}

fn random_arrays<const N: usize>(size: usize) -> Vec<Array<N>> {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let mut gen = || rng.gen_range(-100.0..100.0);
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..size {
        v.push(Array([0.0; N].map(|_| gen())));
    }
    v
}

fn fold<const N: usize>(v: Vec<Array<N>>) -> Vec<Array<N>> {
    let result = v.iter().map(|a1| {
        v.iter().fold(Array::default(), |acc, a2| {
            let d = *a2 - *a1;

            acc + d
        })
    });

    result.collect()
}

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let mut group = c.benchmark_group("Array fold");

    for i in (5000..=5000).step_by(10) {
        group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("Length 1", i), &i, |b, i| {
            b.iter(|| fold::<1>(black_box(random_arrays(*i))))
        });
        group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("Length 2", i), &i, |b, i| {
            b.iter(|| fold::<2>(black_box(random_arrays(*i))))
        });
        group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("Length 3", i), &i, |b, i| {
            b.iter(|| fold::<3>(black_box(random_arrays(*i))))
        });
        group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("Length 4", i), &i, |b, i| {
            b.iter(|| fold::<4>(black_box(random_arrays(*i))))
        });
        group.bench_with_input(BenchmarkId::new("Length 5", i), &i, |b, i| {
            b.iter(|| fold::<5>(black_box(random_arrays(*i))))
        });
    }

    group.finish();
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

I also changed the graph's colors as the default ones were hard to distinguish.

Comment: Interesting. Can you share the criterion setup you used so others can inspect and verify? If legit, it could be a missed optimization or mis-optimization. You could probably file an issue with the Rust team.

Comment: the choice of colors in that chart is terrible, it's all shades of blue-greens, hard to distinguish. anyway, you'll want to look at the assembly output. the optimizer likely is making vastly different decisions based on the sizes.

Comment: Please share definitions for `Array` including your implementations for the math ops. BTW, I think you can use `reduce` instead of `fold` in this scenario.

Comment: I have added the full setup as requested and also changed the colors of the graph.
@PitaJ I didn't since in my actual project I can't use reduce.

Comment: I find the generated asm of `fold::<2>` weird but I cannot explain why. I've marked important areas for you. https://rust.godbolt.org/z/9fbGjoPrx

Comment: The `shl`, `shr` and `or` operations on `rdx` and `rsi` suggest that for `N = 2` the two floats are stored in one 64 bit general purpose register, whereas in the other cases the value of `a1` is persisted in `N` separate `xmm*` registers.

Comment: @NiklasMohrin So this means it's a compiler mishap? Should I file an issue for it?

Comment: `-C opt-level=3` results in the seemingly wrong optimization. `-C opt-level=z` doesn't display the same issue. So I'd guess it's on the LLVM side, and the pessimized performance may or may not be consistent across CPUs.

Comment: I suspect it may be reproducible in C as well.

Comment: I see, I guess this is hardly preventable then as this is code for a library, or is there a way I could circumvent this somehow? Thanks a lot for you answers by the way!

Comment: @Canleskis I am not 100% sure how to proceed from here, I suppose opening an issue on github.com/rust-lang/rust with your code is your best bet